# Does empty slot (by the proposal being offline) mean no transaction processing for 12 seconds?

Tags: blocks, consensus, slots

guys!

When a validator chosen as the block proposal in a certain block goes offline, the slot goes empty.

Does that mean that no single transaction is successfully processed for the slot (for 12 seconds)?;
so literally, ETH wasted 12 seconds doing nothing useful?

Thanks!